# Can't access temp table created from code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, temp-tables

I'm having a really weird issue with temp tables. I create a temp table in code and it shows up under tempdb.sys.tables in MSSQL, but if I try and select from it I get a

Invalid object name '#Update'.  Error

If I cut and paste the create temp table sql directly from my code into mssql manager and run it, it will create the temp table and I can select from it. It will then show two ideintical temp tables in tempdb.sys.tables.

Maybe I'm overlooking something, but this seems odd.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Execute the command to make a temp table
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "create table #UpdatePOS (Store_ID nvarchar(50), POSItem_Id nvarchar(50), POSSalesDate datetime, LastModifiedWhen datetime, UpdateResult bit, QTY decimal(18,0));";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: database cannot have two identical tables, you're missing something in their names, is it sys or dbo?

Comment: I was assuming it was dbo, but maybe it is being created as a sys table?

Comment: hm, can I answer question about what had been created on your server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: your question was "maybe it is being created as a sys table?" - I cannot answer this question, as I have no idea what is created in your database, you should check it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local temporary tables (prefixed with a single # symbol) disappear after the connection on which it was created disconnects.  If you are creating that table with one `SqlConnection` object and trying to access it via another, you may want to use a global temp table (prefixed with ##) but because that will remain in existence after you disconnect you will have to truncate any data before running your SQL.

More reading: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I can actually access the temp table through sql server management studio using ##, but it seems like the problem is something else. If I create it with only one #, I can see it in the sys.temp table but I can't select on it

Comment: Can you select from the ## table?

Comment: Yes, I can select from ##, but not #. Do you think because it was created using the asp.net process and when I go into sql server management studio and try to select I can't because it is out of scope?

Answer (score 2):

There can never be two identical tables, there would have been some change in the name which you might have not noticed. Temp table created with # (local temp table) in `SqlConnection` would not be accessible in MSSQL manager as it is considered as another session and local temp tables are accessible only in the same session. You will be able to do it using ## as they are global temp tables

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I came to in the above comment :)

Comment: As my reputation did not allow me to comment, I posted it as an answer